# Running ADF apps in Chrome vs IE

Tags: css, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

So, I have this application that uses the LOV to search from the given list of items. When I run this application in Chrome, my LOV input field looks slightly different from the way it looks inside the IE. Moreover, the Chrome view is missing the "x" sign that allows you to delete the entire input text. Why do they have a different behavior in Chrome vs IE? Thank you in advance!

IE view
[image]

Chrome view[image]

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-main-differences-between-Google-Chrome-and-Internet-Explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior from the browsers native control and not something ADF induced.

Run the below snippet yourself in MS IE/Edge and G Chrome. You will notice the "x" in IE for the first field but not in the second, since it is suppressed via CSS. You may do the same in your ADF projects if it bothers you.

```css
input[id="a2"]::-ms-clear {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" label="With X" id="a1" value="Test"/>
<input type="text" label="Without X" id="a2" value="Test"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!